# HTML form not working when put in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this:

```js
(function (){
 var ad = document.getElementById("layerad");

    var slide1 = "<form action='' method='get'><p>Toppings</p><p><input name='topping1' type='checkbox' value='c'> Cheese</p><p><input name='topping2' type='checkbox' value='o'> Onions</p><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";

 var container = document.getElementById("container");

 container.onclick = function(){
  this.innerHTML = slide1;
 }

 function closeAd(){
  ad.style.display = "none";
 }
 var closeButton = document.getElementById("close");
 closeButton.onclick = closeAd;

 var style = document.createElement("link");
 style.rel = "stylesheet";
 style.href = "style.css";

 parent.document.body.appendChild(layerad);
 parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
})();
```

```html
<div id="layerad">
    <p id="close">Close[X]</p>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="slide1">
       <img src="slide1.png">
      </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to put the forms in vars because eventually this forms will be coming from a JSON source, but that's not the problem, problem here is that when this loads, I can't interact with the form at all...

Any ideas? The product is an interstitial ad that shows a form.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"I can't interact with the form"_. Yes, that is because every time you click on the form, the HTML is replaced, as you asked it to do. (`container.onclick = ...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put your form inside your `#container` . Place your form in another div and it will work.

```js
(function (){
 var ad = document.getElementById("layerad");

    var slide1 = "<form action='' method='get'><p>Toppings</p><p><input name='topping1' type='checkbox' value='c'> Cheese</p><p><input name='topping2' type='checkbox' value='o'> Onions</p><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";

 var container = document.getElementById("container");

 container.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = slide1;
 }

 function closeAd(){
  ad.style.display = "none";
 }
 var closeButton = document.getElementById("close");
 closeButton.onclick = closeAd;

 var style = document.createElement("link");
 style.rel = "stylesheet";
 style.href = "style.css";

 parent.document.body.appendChild(layerad);
 parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
})();
```

```html
<div id="layerad">
    <p id="close">Close[X]</p>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="slide1">
       <img src="slide1.png">
      </div>           
    </div>
<div id="myForm">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `this.onclick = null;` inside `container.onclick`. This will prevent the form from being replaced every time you click on it.

```js
(function (){
 var ad = document.getElementById("layerad");

    var slide1 = "<form action='' method='get'><p>Toppings</p><p><input name='topping1' type='checkbox' value='c'> Cheese</p><p><input name='topping2' type='checkbox' value='o'> Onions</p><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";

 var container = document.getElementById("container");

 container.onclick = function(){
            this.innerHTML = slide1;
            this.onclick = null;
 }

 function closeAd(){
  ad.style.display = "none";
 }
 var closeButton = document.getElementById("close");
 closeButton.onclick = closeAd;

 var style = document.createElement("link");
 style.rel = "stylesheet";
 style.href = "style.css";

 parent.document.body.appendChild(layerad);
 parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
})();
```

```html
<div id="layerad">
    <p id="close">Close[X]</p>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="slide1">
       <img src="slide1.png">
      </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```